# How to test that one object is a subset of another object in rego

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I'd like to write a Rego rule that checks Kubernetes deployment selectors against the labels declared in the template. The rule should pass if every key/value present in `spec.selector.matchLabels` is present in `spec.template.metadata.labels`.

If I were to write this in Javascript it would look something like this:

```
for(let key of input.spec.selector.matchLabels) {
  assert(input.spec.selector.matchLabels[key] === input.spec.template.metadata.labels[key], `${key} doesn't match`)
}
```

I'm not sure how to write the equivalent in Rego. I've come up with a way to check that keys are present but I don't know how to check the values. Here's what I have so far:

```
selector_match_labels {
    # keys in matchLabels are present in the template labels
    matchLabels := { label | input.spec.selector.matchLabels[label] }
    labels := { label | input.spec.template.metadata.labels[label] }
    count(matchLabels - labels) == 0
    # How to check the values of each key matches?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. Just create a set of key-value pairs instead of a set of keys.

```
matchLabels := { [label, value] | some label; value := input.spec.selector.matchLabels[label] }
labels := { [label, value] | some label; value := input.spec.template.metadata.labels[label] }
count(matchLabels - labels) == 0
```

Comment: Thanks. I see how comprehensions are working now. Your solution generates a set of `[ label, value ]` pairs then compares the sets. That was my initial approach since that's how I think about it in programming languages. I think my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319080/1393668) is more in line with rego's approach. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Here's [another solution](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/iMNzojHVxk) that finds any non-matching value.

```
deny[msg] {
    some label
    val := input.spec.selector.matchLabels[label]
    val != input.spec.template.metadata.labels[label]
    msg = sprintf("template label %s must match selector", [ label ])
}
```

This solution uses `some` to find any key that doesn't match. That's enough to create a deny rule. This is opposite of "allow if all key/values match" which works well enough for a deny rule.

Comment: It turns out my answer does not account work correctly if there is a missing key. It only works if keys are present in both objects with different values. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63317694/1393668) handles all cases.